# Rotate the google map polyline around the certain point

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, coordinates, autodesk-forge, react-google-maps-api

I am working with a 3D model using Autodesk Forge extension Geolocation and displaying it on Google Map (@react-google-maps/api). I have the coordinates of a `polygon` in 3D world coordinates and a `polyline` in latitude and longitude coordinates. I also have the `modelOrigin`, which is the center point of the 3D model. I am trying to rotate the polyline around the modelOrigin, as the same way I am rotating the polygon. The polygon itself rotates fine but the problem is with rotating polyline. I am noticing that the rotation distance for the polyline is too long and the polyline is moving away from the modelOrigin as soon as I try to rotate it.

I am using the `LL842LmvPoint` method of Autodesk Forge Geolocation extension to convert the polyline's latitude and longitude coordinates (lat and lng) into 3D world coordinates and `lmv2LL84Point` method to convert back to lat lng.

This is how I get my polygon (buildingProfile) coordinates and modelOrigin:

```
  const [yAxisLineLatLng, setYAxisLineLatLng] = useState<any>([ { "lat": 40.733288742831924, "lng": -74.15844074123018 }, { "lat": 40.73363656398297, "lng": -74.15844074123018 } ]);
  const [initialBuildingProfile, setInitialBuildingProfile] = useState<any>([]);
  const [initialBuildingProfileLatLng, setInitialBuildingProfileLatLng] = useState<any>([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (!model) return;

    const modelBoundingBox = model.getBoundingBox();
    const { min, max } = modelBoundingBox;
    const profilePolygon = [
      {
        x: min.x,
        y: min.y,
      },
      {
        x: max.x,
        y: min.y,
      },
      {
        x: max.x,
        y: max.y,
      },
      {
        x: min.x,
        y: max.y,
      },
    ];
    const center = modelBoundingBox.center();
    const origin = new (Autodesk.Viewing.Private as any).LmvVector3(...defaultLocation);
    localCS.current = new (Autodesk.Extensions as any).Geolocation.LocalCS(
      origin,
      model.getData().refPointTransform,
      model.getUnitScale(),
      model.getData().placementWithOffset,
    );
    setInitialBuildingProfile(profilePolygon);
    setModelOrigin(center);
  }, [model, defaultLocation]);
```

As soon as I set `initialBuildingProfile` there is an useEffect that triggers another function which is responsible converting buildingProfile from 3d word coords into lat and lng coords

```
  useEffect(() => {
    updateInitialBuildingProfile();
  }, [buildingProfile, isLoaded]);

 function updateInitialBuildingProfile() {
    const buildingProfileLatLng = buildingProfile.map(function (point: any) {
      const thePoint = new (Autodesk.Viewing.Private as any).LmvVector3(
        point.x,
        point.y,
        0,
      );
      const geoLoc = localCS.current.lmv2LL84Point(thePoint);
      return { lat: geoLoc.y, lng: geoLoc.x };
    });
    setInitialBuildingProfileLatLng(buildingProfileLatLng);
  }
```

And the rendering looks something like this:

```
<GoogleMap
  id="buildingOrientation"
  zoom={18}
  onLoad={googleMapLoaded}
  center={{ lat: defaultLocation[1], lng: defaultLocation[0] }}
  mapContainerStyle={{
    height: "440px",
    width: "100%",
  }}
  options={{
    rotateControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    tilt: 0,
  }}
>
  <PolygonF
    paths={initialBuildingProfileLatLng}
    options={{
      strokeColor: "#26282A",
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#5B5C5E",
      fillOpacity: 1,
    }}
  />
  <Polyline
    options={{
      strokeColor: "red",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,
    }}
    path={yAxisLineLatLng}
  />
</GoogleMap>;
```

Result:

[image]

Now rotation part,

```
  // function to rotate the squire polygon on a map.
  function rotatePolygon(angle) {
    const coords = initialBuildingProfile.map((point: any) => {
      const rotatedPoint = rotatePoint(point, modelOrigin, angle);
      return { x: rotatedPoint.x, y: rotatedPoint.y };
    });

    return coords;
  }

function rotatePoint(point: any, origin: any, angle: any) {
  const angleRad = -(angle * Math.PI) / 180.0;
  return {
    x:
      Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) -
      Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) +
      origin.x,
    y:
      Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) +
      Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) +
      origin.y,
  };
}
```

And rotation for polyline(red line on y axis)

```
function rotatePolyline(polyline: any, angle: any) {
    if (!modelOrigin) return;
    const polyline = yAxisLineLatLng;

    const polyline3D = polyline.map((point: any) => {
      const point3D = localCS.current.LL842LmvPoint({ x: point.lng, y: point.lat });
      return { x: point3D.x, y: point3D.y };
    });

    const rotatedPolyline3D = polyline3D.map((point: any) =>
      rotatePoint(point, modelOrigin, angle),
    );

    const rotatedPolylineLatLng = rotatedPolyline3D.map((point: any) => {
      const pointLatLng = localCS.current.lmv2LL84Point(
        new (Autodesk.Viewing.Private as any).LmvVector3(point.x, point.y, point.z),
      );
      return { lat: pointLatLng.y, lng: pointLatLng.x };
    });

    return rotatedPolylineLatLng;
  }
```

Finally, when user clicks on rotate right button I do this:

```
const newCoords = rotatePolygon(15);
setBuildingProfile(newCoords);

const newAxis = rotatePolyline(15);
setYAxisLineLatLng(newAxis);
```

After rotating by 15 degrees, my polygon looks fine but polyline gets far away from my modelOrigin.

[image]

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: I probably won't be able to help here but with such complex code, I'd really suggest that you edit your question to include a working demo (codepen, codesandbox or alike).

Comment: This looks more like google maps work than Autodesk viewer, I think you can re-ask this question as generic google maps help.

Comment: aren't you using the wrong rotation base point? I would expect it to be at the center of the area formed by the polygon and line, or maybe around the polygon center. The rotation happens around a base.